# Getting last ten victories

Tags: mysql

I'm actually have a table for matches, id, team1, team2, date
Where team1 is the winner of the match, I'm trying to get how many victories one team have in his last ten matches.

I managed to get the team's last ten matches this way, but I can't find a way to get the number of wins

```
SELECT * 
FROM matches
WHERE time1 = 13 OR time2 = 13 
ORDER BY data DESC, id ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: im curious why team is `time` in your query

Comment: Do you store the score in this table?

Comment: haha english isnt my first language as you may noticed :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT team1, COUNT(team1) as 'wins'
FROM matches
WHERE team1 = 13 or team2 = 13
GROUP BY team1
LIMIT 10
```

It should give you results like

```
team1 | wins
=====   ====
Bears    5
Tigers   3
Cubs     2
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

```
SELECT time1, COUNT(team1) AS 'wins'
FROM matches
WHERE time1 = 13 OR time2 = 13 
ORDER BY data DESC, id ASC 
LIMIT 10
GROUP BY wins
```

I would suggest adding a separate column for winner, but I think this is what you're looking for...and spell team right.

Comment: You need a "GROUP BY" clause to select anything outside of your aggregate function, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

May be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(time1) 
FROM matches
WHERE time1 = 13 OR time2 = 13 
ORDER BY data DESC, id ASC 
GROUP BY time1 //GROUP BY WINNER TEAM
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This will give you a count of the number of times that you were beaten by some other team in the last ten matches as well as your team's wins as rows, won't it?

Comment: according to the OP, team1 is a winner team, so it will result in the count of wins of a team (any team) in last 10 matches

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT`. By the way, is your "date" column actually named "date"?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM matches
WHERE time1 = 13
```

This will return just the number of wins for a given team. If you need a results table, then use [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19964174/7841):

```
SELECT time1, COUNT(*) AS wins
FROM matches
GROUP BY time1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```